# EditableDropDownList Values Not Showing from dataset datasouce and binding

Tags: c#

Here is my code behind method:

```
        protected void GetFindingTargetIdList()
        {
            eddlTargetid.DataSource = _oegdl.GetFindingTargetId();
            eddlTargetid.DataTextField= "ID";
            eddlTargetid.DataValueField = "NAME";           
            eddlTargetid.DataBind();
        }
```

Here is my DataLayer Method:

```
        public DataSet GetFindingStatusState()
        {
            DataSet resultDs = default(DataSet);

            try
            {
                resultDs = _newdal.FillDataset("procedurename", CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            return resultDs;
        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

editabledropdownlist is not populating, I use the same code for a normal asp:DropDownLIst and get values back as expected, the editabledropdownlist is not binding any of the values of the dataset,